# CCLabel on iPad really slow?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocos2d to make an ipad app and i'm just starting out.

So I added a label to my HelloWorld scene and when I tested it out it was really slow.

Like I was getting 30 - 40 fps out of 60. I figured out that label's size that was causing the drop in fps. It is a fontsize 128 when this happens and I'm just wondering if cclabels are supposed to be this slow or I am doing something wrong.

Here is my code:

```
CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

_label = [CCLabel labelWithString:@"Hello World!" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:128];  
_label.position =  ccp(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);  
_label.color = ccc3(0, 0, 0);  
[self addChild: _label];
```

any feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know what [CCLabel](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/source/browse/trunk/cocos2d/CCLabel.h?spec=svn1496&r=1496) is but I was curious so googled it and found this warning in CCLabel.h:

- @warning Changing the string is as expensive as creating a new CCLabel. To obtain better performance use CCLabelAtlas

And [CCLabelAtlas](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0/interface_c_c_label_atlas.html) docs say:

- It can be as a replacement of CCLabel  since it is MUCH faster.

Comment: yeah, sorry. CCLabel is a label used in the cocos2d engine. However, i am not changing the string unless there is something going on behind the scenes that is changing it. i have indeed seen that class references for both CCLabel and CCLabelAtlas but i dont really have a large font image to compare CCLabel to CCLabelAtlas

Comment: Have you looked at the [Improving Performance section](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices)?